# Who is mapping that page? -- reverse map

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

This comment is copied from mm_types.h file in the linux source code:

```
/*
 ...
 * Each physical page in the system has a struct page associated with
 * it to keep track of whatever it is we are using the page for at the
 * moment. Note that we have no way to track which tasks are using
 * a page, though if it is a pagecache page, rmap structures can tell us
 * who is mapping it.
 ...
 */
```

So, my question is how to find the processes that are referencing or mapping a particular physical page as the comment says? What are those functions that can do this?

Thanks all.